# I want to build request to speak feature in my app similar to twitter spaces can anyone help me?

Tags: agora.io

I have integrated agora voice chat api and want to build feature where audience can request to speak to host and host can allow/not allow as per choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out using Agora Real-time Messaging (RTM) SDK to handle logic for requests such as these.

Using RTM you could have an incoming request appear for the host with an option to accept or confirm. When the requester gets a response that it's been accepted their microphone is enabled.

I don't know what SDK you're using, but there's a detailed blog about using RTM with iOS here:
https://www.agora.io/en/blog/create-real-time-messaging-app-for-ios/

It doesn't cover your exact use-case, but should help you get started.